# How can i make an event to a JComboBox which triggers AFTER selection?

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, itemscontrol, jcombobox

I want to make an event which will be triggered after i make the selection to the JComboBox.
the problem I'm now facing is that when i added an ActionListener, it was triggered when the user clicked on the box but BEFORE he actually chose the new item, thus the action listener was activated all the time on the previous value which was selected in the box. what i want to do is simply changing the title of an JTextArea according to the selection.
I tried doing something like this:

```
 jBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String alt = GetAlgoAreaTitleByChoice();
    panel.remove(jArea);
    currentBest = setArea("",alt);
    currentBest.setBounds(50, 350, 1000, 290);
    panel.add(jArea);
     }
     });
```

and the method inside:

```
private String GetArgsAreaTitleByChoice(){
    String chi = jBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
    if(chi.equals(generalChoice)){
    return "Hello";
    }
    else if(chi.equals(algoChoice)){
    return "World";
    }
    else if(chi.equals(argsChoice)){
    return "Hello";
    }
    return null;
}
```

I've tried using the SELECTED events now like this:

```
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
JComboBox cb = (JComboBox)e.getSource();

    // Get the affected item
    String item = cb.getSelectedItem().toString();

    if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
        panel.remove(jBox);
    textArea = setArea("", item);
        panel.add(jBox);
   }
```

but it seems to remove the area from the panel without adding it back... why is this happening?

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Comment: @Yonatan Nir see my edit

Comment: a) can't reproduce the behavious as you describe it b) the seemingly not-adding-back is self-inflickted pain (by not using a layoutManager) Anyway, why _do_ you remove and re-add ... just change the state of the textArea and be happy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For listening of events from [JComboBox](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) is better implements [ItemListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/itemlistener.html), returns two events `SELECTED/DESELECTED`

EDIT

if you remove/add JComponent(s) on Runtime and in already visible container, then you have to call (as least code lines)

```
revalidate();
repaint();
```

Comment: using either action or itemListener is mainly a matter of taste, the latter only really needed if you want to know the deselected item (no way of getting it with an actionListener as that is fired _after_ the selection has changed). Without that need, go for the most simple, that is Action.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple demonstration with a sample code :

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Tester {

    public Tester(){

        JComboBox box = new JComboBox();
        box.addItem("One");
        box.addItem("Two");
        box.addItem("Three");


        box.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e){

                if(e.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.SELECTED){

                    e.getItem();  //Do what ever you want :))

                }
            }
        });

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().add(box);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Tester tester = new Tester();
    }
}
```